# Novel that depicts a dystopian city trapped by fog

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

Things I believe I accurately remember:

There was an airship/dirigible on the cover. 
 The MC was a journalist. 
 As stated in question there is a fog around the entire city (which is an island or port town). There are iron ships that go into and out of the fog (but I believe there's nothing on the other side of it). 
 The climax/resolution involves some sort of portal to a mirror world or some-such, and a battle on board an airship.
 The book itself was new, and I'm pretty sure it was recently published around 2012, although this may be inaccurate. 
 Mostly, it was GOOD.

I asked this question a year or so ago on r/TOMT but it was of no help.

Comment: I really have to stop trying to read and make sense of SE at night. Wasn't until the third read that I realised you said the city was trapped by ***fog***, not trapped by a frog.

Comment: @Janus Now THAT would be a good read

Comment: @user14111 - Main character, I assumed.

Comment: @user14111 Googling r/TOMT gives leads me to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue), which fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a book I read a few years ago called Boneshaker, by Cherie Priest.  Takes place in a steampunk Seattle.  A wall contains poisonous fog which was released during a mining accident.  There is a dirigible on the cover -- reflected in the protagonist's goggles.